# How does my controller know when to execute one method over another (update/insert) if I have the same URL on the call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

The insert:

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertDirector(Director director)
{
    myConnection.Open();
    var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.AWD_Directors (AwardTitleId, PersonId, NameId,  DirectorSequence, IsOnBallot, Concatenation, WhoEntered, WhoChanged) VALUES (" + director.AwardTitleId + ", " + director.PersonId + ", " + director.NameId + ", " + director.DirectorSequence + ", " + director.IsOnBallot + ", '" + director.Concatenation + "', 0, 0)";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

The update:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateDirector(Director director)
{
  myConnection.Open();
  var query = "UPDATE dbo.AWD_Directors SET NameId=" + director.NameId + ", DirectorSequence = " + director.DirectorSequence + ", IsOnBallot = " + director.IsOnBallot + ", Concatenation = '" + director.Concatenation + "' WHERE AwardTitleId = " + director.AwardTitleId + "AND PersonId = " + director.PersonId + " AND NameId = " + director.NameId;
  var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myConnection.Close();
}
```

The insert route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "InsertDirector", routeTemplate: "api/awards/directors", defaults: new
{
    controller = "Awards", action = "InsertDirector"
});
```

The update route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "UpdateDirector", routeTemplate: "api/awards/directors", defaults: new
{
    controller = "Awards",
    action = "UpdateDirector"
 });
```

What are naming conventions that I can use to improve what I have?

*By the way, never mind the in-line SQL. This will be changed later.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention for REST is that we use HttpMethods for CRUD operations selection:

- GET - Read opeation (list and GetById)
- POST - Insertion
- **PUT** - Udpating
- DELETE - Deletion

The detailed description: [Creating a Web API that Supports CRUD Operations](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)

And then with a very default Routing setting (see more here: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) )

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",   // the Director as controller
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

So, we've just instructed the Web API infrastructure, that if there is method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertDirector(Director director) ...
```

It will be used for creation, and the HttpMethod used must be `POST` and

```
//[HttpPost]
[HttpPut]      // !! Attention, here is the difference
public void UpdateDirector(Director director)...
```

the `UpdateDirector` will be called if the HttpMethod is `PUT`

*NOTE: because during the update we do have the ID of existing product, the Update method should look like:*

```
// the id parameter is a convention as well, 
// to be sure that we are updating existing item
// so this would be better
public void UpdateDirector(int id, Director director)...
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a case of Insert/Update I assume you would have an ID field somewhere (hidden HTML). You should call the same method and the method would have logic as following

If the ID is null or ZERO. Do an insert
If the ID is positive number. Do an update where the ID = html.ID